# refresh data on home page using future builder on button click - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-webui

i have an app with two screens, home and update page.
The home page displays a list of items and the update page updates the items.

I am having difficulties refreshing the home page to display current updates when I pop back to it.

How can I refresh the home page when I route back to it.

See the code to navigate to update page

```
// home page


       // build the list widget
          Widget _buildTaskWidget(task) {
            return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.assignment),
                title: Text(task['name']),
                subtitle: Text(task['created_at']),
                onTap: () async {
                  await Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => UpdateTask(task: task),
                    ),
                  );
                  await fetchAllTask();
                });
          }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchAllTask(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List tasks = snapshot.data;
              listItems = tasks;

              return _buildTaskList(tasks);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Center(
              child: ShowLoader(),
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddTask()));
        },
        tooltip: 'Add Task',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

// update page to navigate back to home page

```
onPressed: () async {
              var res = await updateNewTask(_taskTextInput.text,
                  _vendorTextInput.text, _amountTextInput.text, id);
              print(res);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
```

Comment: I didn't quite get your code but in such situations i would use a state management solution something like provider. Each time you update any list item notify all listening widgets and your done.

Answer (score 0):

[FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) only runs the asynchronous task when its parent is built. To force a rebuild, you can call `setState()` after Navigating to the next page. Doing so refreshes the current Screen before navigating to the next.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(...).then((_) => setState(() {}));
```

Another approach that you can also consider looking into is with the use of [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) - this Widget rebuilds when change in Stream is detected.